# CodeIgniter Table Class displaying duplicate rows

Tags: codeigniter, duplicates

I've been trying to find the problem for a while now but can't see any, would really like some help in finding the issue.

In my controller I'm building a table and echoing it out onto another page, but when I see the results, they are written twice.

```
        $results = $this->main_model->search();

        $table_row = array();
        foreach ($results->result() as $product)
        {
          $table_row = NULL;
          $table_row[] = $product->product_id;
          $table_row[] = $product->title;
          $table_row[] = $product->description;
          $table_row[] = $product->price;
          $table_row[] = $product->stock;
          $table_row[] = $product->cat_name;
          $table_row[] = $product->subcat_name;
          $table_row[] = anchor('admin/edit/' . $product->product_id, 'edit');

          $this->table->add_row($table_row);
        }    

        $table = $this->table->generate($results);

        $data['table'] = $table;

        $this->load->view('search',$data);
```

Would really appreciate some help, I think there is a problem with the way I'm returning results, not entirely sure what it is though. I've tried a couple of ways but am pretty new to this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you're having duplicates beacause you're adding rows manually with this code

```
foreach ($results->result() as $product)
    {
      $table_row = NULL;
      $table_row[] = $product->product_id;
      $table_row[] = $product->title;
      $table_row[] = $product->description;
      $table_row[] = $product->price;
      $table_row[] = $product->stock;
      $table_row[] = $product->cat_name;
      $table_row[] = $product->subcat_name;
      $table_row[] = anchor('admin/edit/' . $product->product_id, 'edit');

      $this->table->add_row($table_row);
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Change the this line

```
$results_table = $this->table->generate($results);
```

To this

```
$results_table = $this->table->generate();
```

Comment: Sorry I've been trying to figure it out, but if I remove the last line of code that you pointed out, I can't return anything to the view. It gives me an undefined variable error for $results_table in my controller function

Comment: I think I tried that before when I was rampaging some solutions, but it works. Thank you for helping me

Comment: I'm glad I could help you out

Answer (score 0):

`$this->table->generate();`  It Returns a string containing the generated table. Accepts an optional parameter which can be an array or a database result object in case you have not added the rows manually.

But in your case you have already added the rows by

```
 $this->table->add_row($table_row);
```

and then again you are adding them in the

```
 $results_table = $this->table->generate($results);
```

instead comment the line of add row

```
$table_row = array();
        foreach ($results->result() as $product)
        {
          $table_row = NULL;
          $table_row[] = $product->product_id;
          $table_row[] = $product->title;
          $table_row[] = $product->description;
          $table_row[] = $product->price;
          $table_row[] = $product->stock;
          $table_row[] = $product->cat_name;
          $table_row[] = $product->subcat_name;
          $table_row[] = anchor('admin/edit/' . $product->product_id, 'edit');

//          $this->table->add_row($table_row); comment this line
        }    

        $results_table = $this->table->generate($results);
```

Comment: I've tried commenting that out but like Fabio said it doesn't make sense to me either